# Handling a JSON empty List from Controller to html

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, controller

I have a text button in my html which takes a certain value from the user, searches for its occurrence in the database and returns the result if the value is present in the database.

I am using Spring framework. I have a controller class which then passes to serviceimplmentation method for searching for the occurrence of the word. The controller returns a list.

In this, there may occur an instance when a user enters a name which may not be present in the database. So in this case how do I handle if there is no data about the word in the database that the user has entered? What I want to accomplish is that, I want to pass the data from controller and display to the user. So, if there is no data, is there a way for me to display an error message  stating" there is no data corresponding to the value you entered" without using jquery? Can I do it using controller?

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by adding an appropriate message in the model such as below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/{keyword}")
public String search(@PathVariable("keyword") String keyword) {
    List<Person> searchList = searchService.find(keyword);
    if(searchList.size > 0){
        model.addAttribute("searchList", searchList);
    }
    else{  
        model.addAttribute("noData", "there is no data corresponding to the value you entered");
     }
     return "yourFormViewName";
}
```

On the page, it can be displayed as follows

```
    <c:if test="${not empty noData}">
       Message: ${noData}
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${not empty searchList}">
      <c:forEach items="searchList" var="person">    
        <tr>
          <td>${person.firstName}</td>
          <td>${person.lastName}</td>
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
   </c:if>
```

Comment: Hello!! What I am returnign is the entity in the search class and not a string. So if I have records in the database then I return the entity object say Person. But if the database has no record, then how should I return e message on my html page as a string from the same function?

Comment: Edited my answer. We are returning 2 different attributes(`searchlist` or `noData` message) based  on the data present in `searchList`. On the page, the appropriate if block will be displayed. Hope it helps